# MySQL: Optimal index for between queries

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `geo_ip` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end_ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `start_ip` (`start_ip`),
  KEY `end_ip` (`end_ip`),
  KEY `start_end` (`start_ip`,`end_ip`),
  KEY `end_start` (`end_ip`,`start_ip`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

MySQL seems to be unable to use the indexes for most of my queries, as the `where` clause uses a `between` that falls somewhere between `start_ip` and `end_ip`:

```
select * from geo_ip where 2393196360 between start_ip and end_ip;

+----+-------------+--------+------+-------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys                       | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+-------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | geo_ip | ALL  | start_ip,end_ip,start_end,end_start | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2291578 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+-------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

The table has a few million records. I tried expanding the table, by removing the `start_ip` and `end_ip` columns, and creating a row for every possible value of `start_ip` and `end_ip` as the `id`, then querying the `id`. While that vastly improved query performance, it resulted in the table size growing from less than a gigabyte to tens of gigabytes (the table has other columns obviously).

What else can be done to improve query performance? Can I change the query somehow, or can I index the columns differently to result in a hit? Or perhaps something I haven't thought of yet?

**Edit:**

Strangely, the index is used for certain values. For example:

```
explain select * from geo_ip where 3673747503 between start_ip and end_ip;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys                       | key    | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | geo_ip | range | start_ip,end_ip,start_end,end_start | end_ip | 4       | NULL | 19134 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: Which MySQL version? [This fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc048c/1) (admittedly with no data in the table) seems to attempt to use the index `start_end`.

Comment: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`

Comment: If you're not in need of writing to the table for a while, it could be work it to try an [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html).

Comment: Interesting. I added some data to that fiddle and it still seems to use the start_end index. Not sure why my results are different. I will try `ANALYZE TABLE`, thanks.

Comment: It says analyze status OK.

Comment: ...and still not using the index? The analyze table statement can change MySQL's query plan slightly to better use indexes.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't use the index for that value. However, it does use it when using a different value in the where clause. Both produce exactly one result, the indexed query is fast and the non-indexed query is not. I have updated the question

Comment: I think it depends on the cardinality of those values,if there are too many hits for a certain value the optimizer chooses the other index.Yes,I`m late to the party.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure why, but adding an order by clause and limit to the query seems to always result in an index hit, and executes in a few milliseconds instead of a few seconds.

```
explain select * from geo_ip where 2393196360 between start_ip and end_ip order by start_ip desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys   | key      | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | geo_ip | range | start_ip,end_ip | start_ip | 4       | NULL | 975222 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----------------+----------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

This is good enough for me now, although I would love to know the reasoning behind why the optimizer decides not to use the index in the other case.

Comment: I had a similar query and the order by with limit also made it 10x faster. Would love to know if someone could shed some light on this. The query plan with EXPLAIN shows to be almost identical (using index, using where), but with order/limit shows 'range' type where other is 'all' type

Answer (score 11):

I've just run into the same problem. Since nobody answered the "WHY", and I figured it out, I'll write here an explanation for all future readers.

First, let's dissect the query.

```
where 2393196360 between start_ip and end_ip
```

really means

```
where start_ip <= C and end_ip >= C
```

so the engine will first use the index on `start_ip, end_ip` to fetch all rows for which start_ip is smaller than C, and then further filter out the rows for which end_ip is also bigger than C.

When the engine looks for `start_ip <= C`, and `C` is a value big enough such that most, or all start_ips are smaller than C, this "first pass" will result in a lot of rows. It will happen every time `C` is an IP on the higher end of the IP range.

Now, here's the main thing to realise: **our dataset is made in such a way that for each start_ip, there is only an end_ip value, and this end_ip value is guaranteed to be lower than the next record's start_ip value. We are partitioning a range and the partitions do not overlap. But, in the general case, when it comes to two table fields, this does not have to be the case!**

So, after the 'first pass', the engine will have to look through ALL records that match `start_ip <= C` to make sure that they also match `end_ip >= C`, despite the index. Having `end_ip` as part of the compound index does not do much in our case; it would help only if we had multiple values for `end_ip` for each value `start_ip`, but we only have 1.
To give you an example, pretend that the columns were populated with the following data:

```
start_ip  end_ip
1         10001
1         10002
1         10003
------------
2         10001
2         10002
2         10003
------------
...
------------
9999      10001
9999      10002
9999      10003
```

if you ran a query with `start_ip <= 10000 AND end_ip >= 10000`, notice that ALL rows match the expression. 
On the other hand, in our case, with our ip-ranges dataset, we have the guarantee that only ONE record will match any `start_ip <= C AND end_ip >= C` expression, thanks to the way the ip data is structured. Specifically the record with the biggest value for `start_ip`, among all those that match `start_ip <= C`. That's why adding ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 works in this case, and is the cleanest solution, in my opinion.

---

Edit: I've just noticed that adding the ORDER BY start_ip DESC and LIMIT clauses may not be enough in some cases. If you run the query with a value that is **not covered by any ranges in your data**, for instance with private IPs like 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.*, the engine will still look at all records that match the `start_ip <= C` expression, and the query will be slow. That's because since no records matches the the second part of the expression (`end_ip >= C`), the LIMIT 1 clause never kicks in.

The solution I've found is to construct the query with a join so as to force the engine to first grab the record with the biggest value for `start_ip` where `start_ip <= C`, and only then check if end_ip is also >= C. Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  ( select id FROM geo_ip WHERE start_ip <= C ORDER BY start_ip DESC LIMIT 1 ) limit_ip
  INNER JOIN geo_ip ON limit_ip.id = geo_ip.id
WHERE geo_ip.end_ip >= C
```

This query will perform a single lookup, whether or not the specific ip `C` is covered by the ranges in the table, and it only requires a single index on `start_ip` (as well as `id` as the primary key).

Answer (score 4):

Best index for BETWEEN queries are B-TREE indices. See [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html) on that Topic.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD INDEX myIdx USING BTREE (myCol)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create an index for start_ip and one for end_ip, I found I could get comparable results to Jeshurun's results without doing the order by, using an inner join with the same table:

```
select a.* from geo_ip a inner join geo_ip b on a.id=b.id where 2393196360 >= a.start_ip and 2393196360 <= b.end_ip limit 1;
```

Also you will find MySQL uses a partial index instead of reporting a full-index scan which is more comforting to me.

Answer (score 2):

Adding indices will help.

Note: If your query is sth like

```
where x between a and b AND y between c and d
```

, a `INDEX(x, y)` will **not** improve the performance, but two seperate indices for `x` and `y` will.

Comment: To expand on this: While MySQL will generally only use 1 index per "join" (line in EXPLAIN output), there's an exception for the [index merge optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html)